# How can I edit translated video on a Mac?

Tags: macos, video, movie

There is a movie on my Macbook which has some some inappropriate scenes that I want to edit so I can watch the movie with my family.

I know how to cut scenes (trim) using Quicktime but this will confuse the translation timing on the film (.srt file)

I am wondering how to make the scene freeze (fixed) while the unwanted scene is playing or better, a program that would adjust the timing of the subtitles to match scenes cut so that we didn't have to fast forward through whatever the "censored" still frames look like?

Comment: The best suggestion I have is to hard-code the subtitles using a tool like Handbrake. Once the subtitles are hard-coded you will no longer need the .srt file, and you should be able to use QuickTime or iMovie to chop the file up. The only downside is that hard-coding will cause the film to be re-encoded an additional time, which could result in a slight quality loss.

Comment: well quality is really matters to me :) and i think hard coding will take hours (as i heard) specially for MKV files .. anyway thank you so much for your replay i really appreciate it

Comment: Just use iMovie to insert a black image or whatever you like without changing the duration. There is  Windows app called SubRip that can adjust the timing +/- by X seconds. So it would be a good deal of manual labor, but you could make that adjustment once for each scene, and export a new srt file.

Comment: I have no experience in this area but http://stackexchange.com/search?q=edit+srt+subtitle finds what may be some useful answers under questions such as [How to correct / shift subtitle time in SRT (SubRip) files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12864047/38108) and [What subtitle file editor for '.srt' files supports synchronization?](http://superuser.com/q/49245/84988)

Answer (score 1):

I use [SubMerge](http://www.bitfield.se/submerge/) to load and sync subtitles to movies. I generally look for subtitles in [SRT](http://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html) format. You can usually edit the subtitles texts inserting (or removing), pauses or blanks. A difficult part is that it's not uncommon for subtitles to slowly get out of sync with the film as the latter progresses. Adding - or removing text is really handy to restore synchronization. It is a bit of a laborious process though :)

Once I have the stuff in sync, then I too use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) to change formats if necessary. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you all .. still have some problems ill try to fix it otherwise ill come back here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to find a Video File of Movies or T.V Shows.

Search Your Subtitle on the Internet in any language if you don't find it in our Subtitle list.

Download the .srt file of Video Subtitle in your Computer or Smartphone.

Upload that SRT File here by Clicking Upload Button.

Select your preferred language in which you want to Translate SRT File.

Now Click On Upload+Translate Option.

It takes a few seconds to get your file ready so waits.

Now Download your [Subtitles SRT](https://subtitlecat.online/subtitles-srt) File and Enjoy your Video.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  Also, thank you for your answer. I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your answer, I'm guessing you may be affiliated in some way with the site you're linking to. If so, please disclose this in your answer, otherwise it may get flagged as SPAM.